# How to create custom gateway and custom waves wallet on waves platform

Tags: wavesplatform

Can someone help me creating custom gateway and  customized wallet on waves platform so i can send my erc20 tokens to waves platform?

Answer (score 1):

A good start to build a gateway is:
https://github.com/jansenmarc/WavesGatewayFramework
this framework allows easy implementation.

And here is an example: https://github.com/jansenmarc/WavesGatewayLTCExample
I have used this framework by myself in the past a few times.

The waves wallet is open-source, so forkable, however, to send erc-20 to wavesplatform, you don't strictly need a custom wallet.